# use mysql function for ActiveRecord setter/getter methods

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, point

I have a project using: Ruby on Rails and MySQL.

I have a table with a GEOMETRY field Coordinates with the data type `Point`. I would like to set the value of this field with `WKT "POINT(40 100)"` but when ActiveRecord saves the field it should set the value to `GeomFromText(WKT)` and when reading from the column it should read `AsText(GEOMETRY)`.

Is it possible to configure "SQL-modifiers" for the set and get methods of this field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

For other users having similar problems I have found a solution.

- install gem activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter
- factory = RGeo::Cartesian.factory

  model.Coordinates = factory.point(longitude, latitude)

Cheers

Comment: Can you be more specific?